# Ionic V3 Lazy Loading: Not Working. All js chunks loaded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic3, lazy-loading

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening but every single one of my lazy loaded ionic page loads ALL `*.js` chunks and I am unable to benefit from lazy loading.

Its a fairly large app. Each page load is downloading about 46mb of data, most of which are all `0.js, 1.js, ...`. When going to different pages, I don't see any more `*.js` being downloaded.

Please help!!!!!!.

Lazy Loaded Module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(PostWidgetComponent)
    ],
    declarations: [
        PostWidgetComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [],
    exports: [PostWidgetComponent]
})
export class PostWidgetModule { }
```

App Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent, {
      preloadModules: true
    }),
    ProvidersModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    /*  { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }, */
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was such a dump mistake that I deleted the answer, but putting the "fix" here for reference. I found the mistake while copying app.module and pasting here :)

```
IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent, {
  //preloadModules: true // DELETE DANGER AHEAD
}),
```